# Windows Forms Serialization -Opens Empty File

Tags: c#, serialization, datagridview, mdi

I'm trying to save a BindingList of my objects in an MDI application and then reopen it. When I open the file, I can see a new form, but it appears to contain no data in the DataGridView bound to the object.
Here are the open and save parts:

```
private void OpenFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog=new OpenFileDialog();
    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         string filename = dialog.FileName;
         FileStream fs=new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
         BinaryFormatter bf=new BinaryFormatter();
         Form1 activeForm = null;
         if (ActiveMdiChild == null)
         {
              activeForm = new Form1();
              activeForm.MdiParent = this;
              activeForm.Show();
          }
          else
          {
              activeForm = (Form1) ActiveMdiChild;
          }
          activeForm.tigers =(BindingList<Tiger>) bf.Deserialize(fs);
          fs.Close();
    }
}

private void SaveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string filename = dialog.FileName;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(fs, ((Form1)ActiveMdiChild).tigers);
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

And here is the Tiger definiton:

```
public  class Tiger
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public DateTime Born { get; set; }
    public Image Picture { get; set; }

    public Tiger(string name, int weight, DateTime born)
    {
        Name = name;
        Weight = weight;
        Born = born;
        Picture = Image.FromFile("D:\\icon.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Beginners often choose MDI because it seems to be the easiest solution but then they struggle to get their MDI windows to work. I don't know how you are using MDI but it is very possible it is the wrong choice.

Comment: Hey, it's a college assignment.

Comment: Is the instructor saying to use MDI specifically?

Comment: MDI means multiple-document interface. It is designed for applications like word processors where there is a one-for-one correspondence of independent documents and each MDI window. If your instructor is teaching the use of MDI just to get additional child windows then that is not good. See [About the Multiple Document Interface (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644908(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: If you could explain your requirements adequately enough to write code from and/or provide just the minimum code relevant to the problem then you are more likely to get help but explaining your requirements more than what is here is important.

Comment: I don't like my .net instructor, but I kind of have no choice. OK, so I have many Child Windows, where I have a DataGridView bound to the BindingList tigers of that Child WIndow. And all the add,delete, update stuff. So, I want to be able to save that tables of tigers in a file, and then to open it in the current active Child Window. If no window is open-I want the Parent to create one and open the file inside of it